# Value of arg changes in funcall in clisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to learn clisp by self-study. But utterly confused how to handle variables. Given below a recursive function "mul" for multiplying two integers (+ or -) and get the result with proper sign. "mul" uses another recursive function "sum".

```
(defun sum (n1 n2)
   "Returns the sum of two integers"
   (assert
      (and (numberp n1) (integerp n1))
      (n1)
      "N1 must be an integer,instead it's ~S"
      n1)
   (assert
      (and (numberp n2) (integerp n2))
      (n2)
      "N2 must be an integer,instead it's ~S"
      n2)
   (cond ((zerop n1) n2)
         ((< n1 0) (sum (1+ n1) (1- n2)))
         (( > n1 0) (sum (1- n1) (1+ n2)))))

(defun mul (n1 n2)
   "Returns the product of two integers"
   (assert
      (and (numberp n1) (integerp n1))
      (n1)
      "N1 must be an integer,instead it's ~S"
      n1)
   (assert
      (and (numberp n2) (integerp n2))
      (n2)
      "N2 must be an integer,instead it's ~S"
      n2)
    (let*  ((s ( if (zerop n1) 0
                 (sum n2 (mul (if (<  n1 0) (1+ n1) (1- n1)) n2))))(r s) )            
         (if (or (and (> n1 0) (> n2 0)) (and (> n1 0) (< n2 0)))  r  
         (if (or (and (< n1 0) (> n2 0)) (and (< n1 0) (< n2 0)))  (- r)  0))))
```

When I run

> (mul 4 4) or (mul -3 4)

I get correct result with proper sign. But

> (mul 3 -4) or (mul -3 -4)

gives wrong result of -4 and 4 respectively. It seems that else clause changes the value of n2 to negative during sucessive calls to mul. Can somebody explain me what am i doing wrong and how "-r" makes n2 negative.
Thanks in advance.

Here are the trace for different values of n1 and n2

```
MATCH> (mul 3 4)
1. Trace: (MUL '3 '4)
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 4
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '4)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 8
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '8)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 12
1. Trace: MUL ==> 12
12
MATCH> (mul 3 -4)
1. Trace: (MUL '3 '-4)
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -4
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '-4)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -8
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '-8)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -12
1. Trace: MUL ==> -12
-12
MATCH> (mul -3 4)
1. Trace: (MUL '-3 '4)
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 4
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '-4)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 0
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 4
1. Trace: MUL ==> -4
-4
MATCH> (mul -3 -4)
1. Trace: (MUL '-3 '-4)
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -4
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '4)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 0
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -4
1. Trace: MUL ==> 4
4
```

As can be seen so long n1 is positive mul gives correct results. The problem arises when n1 is negative and the "else call" gets executed - then sum gets called with sign of n2 changed. Is it because of ( -r) ? if so why it happens ? My understanding is that n2, s and r are three separate variables and value of r should not change n2 . Am I correct ?
If not I shall be thankful if someone explains me their relation. I may not use this complicated code as pointed out by usepa but the explanation will be a great help in my understanding of lisp variables.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried tracing your code?  Since you're using globally defined recursive functions, you can simply evaluate `(trace sum)` and `(trace mul)`, and then when you call, e.g.,  `(mul 3 -4)` you'll see all the calls to `mul` and `sum`, and you should be able to identify where things begin to go awry.

Comment: Yes. Here are two traces for ( -3 4) and (3 -4)MATCH> (mul -3 4)
1. Trace: (MUL '-3 '4)
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 4
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '-4)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 0
2. Trace: (SUM '4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> 4
1. Trace: MUL ==> -4
-4
MATCH> (mul 3 -4)
1. Trace: (MUL '3 '-4)
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '0)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -4
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '-4)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -8
2. Trace: (SUM '-4 '-8)
2. Trace: SUM ==> -12
1. Trace: MUL ==> -12
-12
MATCH>

Comment: That is unreadable in a comment because all the indentation is lost.  Use the **edit** button under the question and add the information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mul` procedure seems overly complicated. I would refactor the procedures as follows:

```
(defun sum (n1 n2)
  (cond 
   ((zerop n1) n2)
   ((zerop n2) n1)
   ((> n1 0)   (sum (1- n1) (1+ n2)))
   (t          (sum (1+ n1) (1- n2)))))

(defun mul (n1 n2)
  (cond
   ((or (zerop n1) (zerop n2)) 0)
   ((< n1 0) (mul (- n1) (- n2)))
   (t        (sum n2 (mul (1- n1) n2)))))
```

Comment: Given that you're using `zerop`, consider also using `plusp` and `minusp` instead of the explicit comparisons against zero. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_minusp.htm

Comment: The simplified code works.Yes my code was overly complicated. Thanks

Comment: @kkp if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: It does provide me an alternate solution. But my quaries regarding the error in my code remains unanswered. Is the code complicated or totally wrong ? I have added the traces to my question. Eager to know to the behaviour of three variables n2, s and r. This will clear my confusion regarding variables in clisp.

Answer (score 1):

The following does not answer the question, but might help you to fix the problem.

First I would improve the formatting a bit. Also the `ASSERT` can be replaced with the shorter `CHECK-TYPE`. Setting the `debug` value to max helps with tracing. With an interpreter it might not be necessary, but [Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com) - see below - uses a compiler.

```
(defun sum (n1 n2)
  "Returns the sum of two integers"
  (declare (optimize (debug 3)))
  (check-type n1 integer)
  (check-type n2 integer)
  (cond ((zerop n1) n2)
        ((< n1 0) (sum (1+ n1) (1- n2)))
        ((> n1 0) (sum (1- n1) (1+ n2)))))

(defun mul (n1 n2)
  "Returns the product of two integers"
  (declare (optimize (debug 3)))
  (check-type n1 integer)
  (check-type n2 integer)
  (let ((s (if (zerop n1)
               0
             (sum n2 (mul (if (< n1 0)
                              (1+ n1)
                            (1- n1))
                          n2)))))            
    (cond ((or (and (> n1 0) (> n2 0))
               (and (> n1 0) (< n2 0)))
           s)
          ((or (and (< n1 0) (> n2 0))
               (and (< n1 0) (< n2 0)))
           (- s))
          (t 0))))
```

Let's try it in [Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com):

```
? (trace sum mul)
NIL
? (mul -2 1)
0> Calling (MUL -2 1) 
 1> Calling (MUL -1 1) 
  2> Calling (MUL 0 1) 
  <2 MUL returned 0
  2> Calling (SUM 1 0) 
   3> Calling (SUM 0 1) 
   <3 SUM returned 1
  <2 SUM returned 1
 <1 MUL returned -1
 1> Calling (SUM 1 -1) 
  2> Calling (SUM 0 0) 
  <2 SUM returned 0
 <1 SUM returned 0
<0 MUL returned 0
0
```

You can see that `(mul -1 1)` does the right thing, but `(mul -2 1)` does not.